# windows security alert windows firewall has blocked some features of this program message coming for every new build of my application

Tags: .net, visual-studio, publish, firewall, windows-firewall

I made a .net win forms application which uses ftp so windows shows `windows security alert: windows firewall has blocked some features of this program` message for every new version of my application any idea how to fix this so user does not have to press unblock for every new build of my application?

I publish my application using visual studio publish option & new version get pushed to client machines automatically. details for this deployment are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

e.g. For 1.2 version it will only ask for windows firewall permissions only once but for 1.3 it will ask again.

Comment: See if setting FtpWebRequest.UsePassive = true makes a difference.

Comment: @HansPassant any idea if ClickOnce deployment creates a seprate version for every publish or it uses the same path and exe name?

Comment: Is the firewall rule added bu port? or by .exe?

Comment: Just to troubleshoot try changing the rule by port instead of .exe. Maybe the firewall knows the differences between your app versions somehow.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is by design in the windows firewall security model. As answered [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/10440/6797)

Answer (score 0):

What security zone have you set? ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h43h8t7f(v=vs.80).aspx )
This could be related to your problem, since it affects the set of permissions granted to your application.
Another possible cause might be the lack of signature (second note) ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hafybdaa(v=VS.80).aspx )
Hope it helps.